# What is $\lim_{n\to \infty} {\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!} \over \sqrt[n]{n!}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to solve this limit.
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} {\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!} \over \sqrt[n]{n!}}=L$$

How should I tackle this? 
This is how I tried to solve this problem:

Let $(x_n) = \sqrt[n]{(n)!} \quad n \gt 1 $

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} {x_n+1 \over x_n}=L $$
According to ratio test:
$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} {x_n+1 \over x_n}= \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\sqrt[n]{n!}}=\sqrt[n]{\lim_{n\to \infty} {\sqrt[n]{n!}}}=1 $$

I'm sorry for misspelling the problem first time.

Comment: Try converting the radicals to exponents.

Comment: This might a duplicated question

Comment: Show $\lim\sqrt[n]{n}$ exists and is non-zero, and you are done.

Comment: the searched Limit should be $1$

Comment: In the revised version, show that $$(n!)^{1/n}\sim n/e$$

Comment: Oh, and by the way: *This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:
$$\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{n!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} <\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}<\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n+1]{n!}}.$$
Taking limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (n!)^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}\le L \le \lim_{n\to\infty} (n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \Rightarrow$$
$$1\le L \le 1 \Rightarrow $$
$$L=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Using Riemann Sums,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\log\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(\frac kn\right)\\
&=\int_0^1\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\[9pt]
&=-1\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!^{1/n}}{n}=\frac1e\tag{2}
$$
Applying $(2)$ to $n+1$ and $n$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)!^{1/(n+1)}}{n!^{1/n}}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{(n+1)!^{1/(n+1)}}{n+1}\frac{n}{n!^{1/n}}\\
&=1\cdot\frac1e\cdot e\\[6pt]
&=1\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$